# What does the "&" mean in in a Bean Name?

Tags: spring, spring-el

I'm looking at a Spring `Qualifier` annotation as follows:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("&fooStreamBuilder")
private FooFactoryBean fooFactoryBean;
```

I haven't seen the "&" in an annotation like this before.  What is it and what does it do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a bean is a factory bean (a bean that creates a bean `FooFactory implements FactoryBean`), the factory instance bean name is `&foo` whereas the bean name is `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.  In the latest spring docs:

> To access a factory bean itself, the bean name should instead be
>   prefixed with a (&) symbol.

What this means:

- If I omit the "&", I get a reference to the bean created by the
  factory (a `Foo`).
- If I use the "&", I get a reference to the actual
  factory (a `FooFactoryBean`).

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions

Comment: That is not SpEL, it's simply a bean (or factory bean) name in that context (`@Qualifier`). But the same applies with SpEL when referencing beans, as the document you cite notes.